# Angular: when update from 8 to 9 - hammerjs + @angular/platform-browser stopped working

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I'm using hammerjs for detecting swipe on a small Angular 8 app.

I followed this article - https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/gestures-in-an-angular-application-dde71804c0d0 - and I'm using hammerjs with @angular/platform-browser.

However, when 3 days ago Angular 9 was released - I updated with no issues, but now swiping detection is not working at all :( ... don't see errors or warnings.
Also - didn't see any notes for platform-browser changes in the update release notes.

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same issue and managed to come across [this article](https://indepth.dev/exciting-times-ahead-be-ready-for-angular-9/#hammerjs-is-now-optional) which has solved my problem.

> **hammerjs is now optional** 
>   In earlier versions hammerjs was required to add gesture support, it is optional now and all implementation used internally is removed, you can use HammerModule from @angular/platform-browser.

Simply adding the `HammerModule` import to my `AppModule` fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Stefan :) ... I impored HammerModule same way I did for BrowserModule - and it worked like a charm :)
Cheers ;)